# Forked Grails VM exited with erro

Tags: grails

Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Answer (score -1):

In Java 8, [MaxPermSize has been removed](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html).

As an example, if you build your Java 8 application with Maven, add the following:

```
MAVEN_OPTS -Xmx512m
```

Comment: which class I add?in buildConfig.GROOVY